# Can you setup security trimming with code first JSS?

Tags: security, jss

We want to restrict some pages that are behind a login on a JSS site. We use code-first development.

Is is possible to setup the security in the /data/*.yml files? Or should we update the security of the items after a `jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary` from the Content Editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore item-based security cannot be managed/applied via disconnected data, only through Sitecore security-management tools.

That said, you could theoretically add custom security-related information to your disconnected data, ensure the JSS app manifest includes that security-related information, and then customize the JSS app import process to handle that security-related information as you see fit.